# rake corrupts development database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, minitest, rake-test

When I run `rake` to run specific/all test(s), it corrupts development database.

I verified that db for each environment is different.

**database.yml**

```
postgre_common_config: &postgre_common_config
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: postgres # if using default PostgreSQL user then the value should be: postgres
  password: postgres
  host: localhost

development:
  database: mag_development
  <<: *postgre_common_config

test:
  database: mag_test
  <<: *postgre_common_config

production:
  database: mag_production
  <<: *postgre_common_config
```

**test_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end
```

This is really annoying as it takes lot of time to prepare data to test specific feature manually. Please help.

Comment: Did you created a ***DB*** with name `mag_test`?

Comment: What do you mean by it corrupts the development database? Are you saying that when you run your tests, it leaves your test data in your development database?

Comment: Please post the rake command and all parameters you are using for this => "I run rake to run specific/all test(s)"...This is where to start.

Comment: Corrupts development database means it removes rows from many tables especially relation tables. Which make stale data and of no use. I have to prepare test data again which take lot of time.

Comment: Commands to run all tests `spring rake`, specific test `spring rake TEST=test/services/wordpress/new_post_test.rb`

Comment: Okay. I don't use spring, so maybe someone who does will come in and help. Question:  If you use standard $rake (without spring) does it cause the same problem to your database?